# How do I remove fake remote branches I have after migrating from git-svn to git?

Tags: git, migration, branch, git-svn

I've been using git-svn for a while (everyone else on my team has been using svn directly). We decided that we will all start using git. In order to do this, I used the git repo that is my "side" of git-svn like such:

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:mycompany/myproject.git
$ git push -u origin master
```

This went fine, but when the process was complete I had retained all these ridiculous branches that git-svn had created when I first started using it, with one little kink; git would no longer even acknowledge that they were branches. Here's what my list looked like:

```
$ git branch -r
domain_integration
dot-org
dot-org@1977
email-edit-page
origin/account-integration
origin/master
origin/stable
prototype_to_jquery-1.1.0
stable@1976
tags/development-1.1.0.0
tags/pre-2011-02-08
tags/production-1.0
tags/stable-1.0.0
tags/stable-1.0.1
tags/stable-1.1.0
tags/stable-1.1.0.1
trunk-stash
```

These were annoying, though I knew where they came from (mostly), but now I can't even delete them. This happens:

```
$ git branch -d trunk-stash
error: branch 'trunk-stash' not found.
```

I was able to fix some of these by going into .git/refs/remotes and just deleting them, but there were only a few there. The only other place i can find them is in .git/info/refs. Which looks something like the following:

```
...
7788d300f0d4370d65a3ccf3e47d90f7fb16b0b4        refs/remotes/tags/stable-1.0.0
aace34d6745080ce2b6b29e927f5d1b050b99511        refs/remotes/tags/stable-1.0.1
58bd2ac23d5979ff61bd6305df18f8a5da50f888        refs/remotes/tags/stable-1.1.0
644fd55fcdf2569305cdbe0b6fefb9f247625658        refs/remotes/tags/stable-1.1.0.1
bc8e9f9177c9612aceb55624adea1b02e9e8620f        refs/remotes/trunk
69493e14345e6a7a4db324935bccd6393f201da4        refs/remotes/trunk-stash
25b7024f6c1d38c10400b2c2e7b446aae1e84e06        refs/stash
...
```

I assume this is just associated the branches with their last commits. Does it make sense to delete the "fake" ones? Will this break something? (Will it work?)

Comment: You are listing remote branches with that command; you cannot delete remote branches with `branch -d`. Are you sure you want to delete all historical svn branches? (You  will probably find them in `.git/packed-refs`)

Comment: Yes, those are remote branches. I should have mentioned that and asked the question a little differently. How do I tell git that they no longer exist? You're right about them being in .git/packed-refs, maybe I should just delete them in there. Or perhaps they'll disappear when I allow the database to compress? (I didn't do this at the outset because I know that in certain situations you can lose things when you've gotten git into a strange place. I'll be more confident about that when I straighten a few things out.)

Comment: They will not disappear when you run `git gc`. @MagnusSkog's answer must be the right one: if they don't exist at the remote, the get deleted. If you really, _really_, ___really___ are sure, that you don't need them anymore, you can delete them directly from the refs-packed file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the master branch you can always delete the local repo and re-clone it. That's the easiest if you don't care about anything but the master branch. You can always try:

```
git remote prune origin
```

To get rid of remote references that are no longer in origin but kept locally.

Comment: This, oddly, does nothing. Maybe it would have gotten rid of the ones that I already got rid of manually when I deleted them from .git/refs/remotes, but now it says nothing and doesn't change the result of git branch -r.

Comment: Then it means those references are in fact on the remote. You need to delete them on the remote if you want to get rid of them completely, e.g. "git push origin :account-integration" if you want to delete the remote branch account-integration, note the colon.

Comment: Sorry, I've made this confusing by including the origin/* branches. Those exist (ie I can see them on github) and I want them to remain. What github denies existing are, for example "domain_integration". I don't even know what the equivalent command would be for that, as I don't think it would be "git push :domain_integration" (which I tried anyway). domain_integration doesn't appear in the .git/config. If I try to check it out, it tells me I'm in a detached HEAD state. (Then git branch will tell me that I'm on "(no branch)".)

Comment: If you get a detached HEAD state it must be a tag and not a branch. Can you try "find . | grep domain" in the .git folder to see where it is?

Comment: $ find . | grep domain gives me 
./logs/refs/remotes/domain_integration I think the key here is that git-svn imported these things and got them into a state that defies internal git logic, meaning that it won't work to think in those terms. I could be wrong (or I could be misunderstanding). At this point I'm most likely to simply clone a clean version, since the prune didn't work and I can just backup what I had before.

Comment: What are these branches 'dot-org@1977', 'stable@1976'? How can i get these stale ones deleted ?

Comment: (Many months later) My first comment was misleading, "git remote prune origin" didn't work. I'm sure that deleting and re-cloning would have indeed worked, but unfortunately at this point I can't remember how I solved it, most likely the delete and re-clone. I'm giving this answer the checkmark for usefulness and ultimately what was likely the solution.